# Solve the two variable differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2+ y^2}$$ 
Is there any method to solve this ?

Comment: Hint: Consider the substitution $x * v = y$

Comment: After substituting , i am not able integrate .

Comment: Can you show us some of your work? What techniques do you know to solve first order ODE's?

Comment: the solution is REALLY ugly according to wolfram alpha

Comment: Sorry actually , i have written different question . I wanna to ask this question    dy/dx = (x² - y²) / x² + y²

Comment: Ok, if it is a different question feel free to attempt it yourself again, then repost if necessary. Best of luck!

Comment: People are using the only  formulation of the question in the edit summary.  So please read carefully the suggestions you receive!  Which you identify in your comment above, as being the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write your equation in the form
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}{1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$